# Github PRs close themselves when their branch is merged from CLI

Tags: github

1. Create a branch and a PR for it.
2. Merge the branch from the CLI, *not* from github
3. Push the branch
4. Within two seconds, the PR at github closes itself

I can see why this is the default behavior - in almost all situations, this makes sense and is handy. But my team has a use case for sometimes keeping PRs open after a branch is merged (related to making exceptions with the deployment system).

Is this behavior an option that can be turned off? I don't see a switch for it anywhere in github repo settings.

Comment: Makes no sense. A PR is by definition a request to merge. Merging fulfills the request and so there is no more open request. But it isn't deleted; in fact, it cannot be deleted. So you can find the pull request later if you need to make a new branch from it so there is no point keeping it open. You can tag/label it if it has some special status post merge. There are lots of possibilities.

Comment: @matt From a code perspective of course you're right, it would make no sense. Our use case here is unique - a server deployment system where a test server is built against a PR, and when the PR is merged the test server should destroy itself. But occasionally we want to keep the test server even after code is merged.